# Dropbox's `filesGetTemporaryLink` throws an uncatchable `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` and terminates Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox, unhandled-exception, unhandled-promise-rejection

To get a download link to the file hosted on Dropbox, I'm using a Dropbox JavaScript API (`7.0.0`):

```js
export const fileDownload = async function fileDownload(fileUUID) {

    let isSucceeded;
    let message;
    let file;
    const dbx = _dropboxFactory();

    try {
        const operationResult = await dbx.filesGetTemporaryLink({
            path: `/${CONFIG_STORAGE.uploader.assetsPath}/${fileUUID}`
        });

        if ("OK" === http.STATUS_CODES[operationResult.status].toUpperCase()) {

            file = Object.freeze({
                length: operationResult?.result?.metadata?.size,
                link: operationResult?.result?.link,
                mime: mime.lookup(operationResult?.result?.metadata?.name),
                name: operationResult?.result?.metadata?.name
            });
            isSucceeded = true;
            message = SYS_MESSAGES.storageFileDownloadSucceeded.code;

        } else {
            isSucceeded = false;
            message = SYS_MESSAGES.storageFileDownloadFailed.code;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        file = "error";
        isSucceeded = false;
        message = "FIL_NOT_FOUND";
    }

    const downloadResult = Object.freeze({
        file,
        isSucceeded,
        message
    });

    return downloadResult;

};
```

The problem is that when the `path` to the file is wrong, I get a Node.js exception:

> (node:9156) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>
>
> (node:9156) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an `async` function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with `.catch()`. To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
>
> (node:9156) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I've tested several options and came to conclusion that the issue is in:

```js
const operationResult = await dbx.filesGetTemporaryLink({
    path: `/${CONFIG_STORAGE.uploader.assetsPath}/${fileUUID}`
});
```

My questions:

1. Why does Node.js claim *«unhandled promise rejection»* or *«promise which was not handled with `.catch()`»* and throws an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` exception if the code, which generates it is wrapped by `try-catch`?
2. Starting Node.js 15.x.x, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. Therefore, how to avoid `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`?

#### A temporal workaround:

To run Node.js with a flag `--unhandled-rejections=warn`.
This will prevent the termination of the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code upon `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

Comment: how come you are awaiting `res.json`?

Comment: you wouldn't await on the server response. You are maybe getting mixed up with `fetch` json response, which you would `await`

Comment: @Rezaa91, I've investigated the case and adjusted the question according to my findings.

Comment: _handleFileOperationException in your catch handler has no handler if it results in an exception, if it's actually something `await`able.  Is it possible that's where the actual unhandled exception is coming from?

Comment: @Joe, I've completely removed `_handleFileOperationException` but the problem still persists. I've simplified the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the Dropbox library and has been solved by the Dropbox team with the release of `7.1.0`. After upgrading the code in the question works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your `fileResponse` function to something like this. You are mixing up `async`/`await` with `.then().catch()` style syntax.

Just wrap your function in a `try-catch`

```js
async function getDocument() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${http() + ip}/downloadDocument`, {
      body: JSON.stringify({fileUUID: oModel.oData[0].documentFile}),
      cache: "no-cache",
      credentials: "same-origin",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors"
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    
    return data;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've rollbacked a code snippet to my initial code version, which is actually very similar to your. But still the problem persists.

Comment: Cheers, and is that try...catch wrapped in an async function too?